# how to write this in one line in python

Tags: python

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)  

# we could do these two on one line too, how?

input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

Comment: why is it a requirement to be written in one line? Do you want `input_file = open(file_name).read()` ?

Comment: Just because you *can* write it on one line doesn't mean *it's a good idea to*.  Readability often trumps cleverness here.

Comment: Any python code can be joined by colons on the same line, but the main point is to not.  Python is a language that boasts readability and you miss the point in doing this. :(

Comment: I think the real question here is a poorly worded attempt at "Is there a built-in way to do this?" It's still not a good question to ask here, and this is an awful format to ask it in on top of that, but I think that's what the OP is actually looking for in asking this. I know that's weird with the prompts inside, so I could be wrong, but I like to think that's what was intended here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `with` statement comes handy here. And its good habit to use it when you're working with files, as it takes care of tearing down the objects, and catching exceptions too.

You can read about it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

And here is how you would use `with` in your program:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv
print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

with open(from_file) as input, open(to_file, 'w') as output:

    print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(input.read())
    print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
    raw_input("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")

    output.write(input.read())
    print "Alright, all done."
```

**One liner** -

```
with open(from_file) as in, open(to_file, 'w') as o: o.write(in.read())
```

Tip: 
Writing all this code in one line would decrease its readability.
However, python supports `;` as line terminator.

So you can do something like this:

```
print foo(); print bar(); print baz();
```

But do remember python's colon `:` operator has more precedence than `;`. Thus if we write -

```
if True: print foo(); print bar();
```

Here either all of the print statements will execute or none.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would care about the number of physical lines in your code, but here's something pretty terse (feel free to edit out any blank lines)

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)  

with open(from_file) as infile: indata = infile.read()


print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %s" % 'no yes'.split()[int(exists(to_file))]
raw_input("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")

with open(to_file, 'w') as outfile: output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."
```

Or, here's another version:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv
print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

with open(from_file) as infile, open(to_file, 'w') as outfile:
    indata = infile.read()
    print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
    print "Does the output file exist? %s" % 'no yes'.split()[int(exists(to_file))]
    raw_input("Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.")
    output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."
```